# how to Spring cloud Gateway SSL crt

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-cloud-gateway

I am creating a spring cloud gateway.
When a request comes in to the gateway, I want to add SSL authentication to the request and send it to the downstream.

The SSL certificate is in a pem file.

The code below is the webclient that does what I want.
I want to create a filter so that my gateway can do something like this
`
@Bean
public WebClient demoWebClient() throws IOException {
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();

```
        SslContext sslContext = createSslContextBuilder(false, false, false, pkcsKey, pkcsCert, pkcsPassword, pkcsCertBundle).build();
        httpClient = httpClient.secure(builder -> builder.sslContext(sslContext));

    ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector);
    return builder.build();
}
```

`